# I am getting 2 rows returned when i'm really expecting one merged row, MySQL and INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have the following SQL:

```
    $queryString = "
        SELECT 
            c.id,
            c.object,
            c.ref,
            c.title,
            o.value
        FROM 
            organisations c
        INNER JOIN 
            organisationType oT ON
            oT.ref = c.ref 
        INNER JOIN 
            options o ON
            oT.value = o.ref
        WHERE c.ref = '585567'
        ORDER BY 
            title
    ";
```

- My organisations table contains information about an organisation (The following is one organisation)

> id, dateModified, object, ref, title
>
> 2312, 2013-04-22 17:34:55,
>   {"__attributes":{"item_id":6868447,"external_id":..., 585567, Test
>   organisation

- My organisationType table contains multiple entries for one organisation as an organisation can be a number of different types. (The following is 2 types assigned to the organisation above)

> id, dateModified, relativeTable, ref, value
>
> 5, 2013-04-22 17:34:55, organisations, 585567, 3
>
> 6, 2013-04-22 17:34:55, organisations, 585567, 2

- Finally my options table contains one row for each type that can be for reference:

> id,   dateModified,    relativeTable, ref,    value
>
> 1,    2013-04-22 16:36:59,     organisations, 2,  Client
>
> 2,    2013-04-22 16:36:59,     organisations, 3,  Partner
>
> 3,    2013-04-22 16:38:27,     organisations, 4,  Vendor

I would like to be able to return one organisation with its type embedded onto the end (o.value)

so my result might be:

```
[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2312
            [object] => ""
            [ref] => "585567"
            [title] => "Test organisation"
            [type] => array( [0] => "Client", [1] => "Vendor" )
        )
```

With my current SQL, I am getting back an array of 2 rows with a duplicate of all components of the row apart from the type which has changed. It's fine, but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really bring back a sub array directly like that in SQL. You can bring back a concatenated field of all the values though. Something like this:-

```
$queryString = "
                SELECT c.id,
                        c.object,
                        c.ref,
                        c.title,
                GROUP_CONCAT(o.value) AS type
                FROM organisations c
                INNER JOIN organisationType oT ON oT.ref = c.ref 
                INNER JOIN options o ON oT.value = o.ref
                WHERE c.ref = '585567'
                GROUP BY c.id, c.object, c.ref, c.title
                ORDER BY title
    ";
```

Comment: Err, that works amazingly. I love you. loll Thank you so much!!!! GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY.. learn something new every day. wey hey!

Answer (score 0):

afaik. it is impossible by mysql to return an array as the field value. you can do it by your own code, adding "order by 1,2,3,4" to your sql expression and collecing an array in the fetch loop, comparing 1-4 columns with previous row.